# Oracle Forms saving data

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracleforms

I want to edit any entry from view form to entry form do some changing and save it now from this save form should not exit now if I press save button again now it should save as a new entry only with change of its asset_serial instead of replace now it is replacing.
I want to save as new entry instead of replacing

```
if :asset_serial is not null then
   :asset_serial:=nvl(getmax,'0001');
   :asset_code:=:I_SEGMENT1||:I_SEGMENT2||:I_SEGMENT3||:asset_serial;
end if;
commit_form;
```

Comment: Punctuation exists for reason. Please, edit your message and write shorter sentences. The way you put it, I have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: It's been a while since I did any forms programming, but maybe you can put this logic in the `ON-UPDATE` trigger to override the default UPDATE process with a INSERT depending on the values you are checking.